# Does googles MLKit work on iOS for Maui in .NET

Tags: ios, xamarin, maui, google-mlkit, firebase-machine-learning

Does the google [MLKit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/guides) work in Maui for iOS?

Specifically I am trying to use the library `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.MLKit.BarcodeScanning` which I believe is possibly the same library as `Xamarin.Google.MLKit.BarcodeScanning` (the joy of random multiple namespaces). I can see that it clearly works for Android and I note that [on their site](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/ios) they suggest that there is a iOS version but I cannot find a binding for iOS in either Maui or Xamarin.

I can also see that there is an alternative (possibly prior) version of I believe the same library `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.MLKit` which clearly has an iOS binding.

Has anyone got any idea if this library can be used on iOS? I assume it's probably possible to create your own binding for the iOS version if it doesn't already exist?

Anyone able to provide any insight?

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone interested I was eventually able to find binding for the MLKit for iOS here

https://www-0.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.MLKit.iOS.BarcodeScanning.JimmyPun610 and a fairly nice complete library here:

https://github.com/JimmyPun610/BarcodeScanner.Mobile